# How can I put a UI Image always on top in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have noticed that in a canvas the elements are drawn from top to bottom so the image above is covered by the image below. The problem is that I want an ui image that is not the last sibling of the canvas to stay on top of all the others. How can I do?

Comment: using GUITexture, this is the default effect. see also https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/unity3d-make-3d-objects-over-gui-surface/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try two ways.

**First.**
Use `Transform.SetAsFirstSibling()` to put the UI Component on top

**Second.**
Use `CanvasGroup.sortingOrder` to help your UI Component grouping.

**Ref**
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Comment: There's no `CanvasGroup.sortingOrder`, not anymore at least. Your only option aside from chaning sibling index is now to create a new Canvas and have it override previous one's sorting order, then add some offset to itself. I created a gist component without any dependencies at https://gist.github.com/somedeveloper00/c48fee9003fbad415874a48859a1c2cf

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of functions you can use for setting orders

```
Transform.SetAsFirstSibling

Transform.SetAsLastSibling

Transform.SetSiblingIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do an edit on Ethan's answer but seems the edit queue is filled so I'm writing it here.
The CanvasGroup solutio does not work. Your other choice aside for changing the sibling index (hierarchy position) is to create a new Canvas, and have it override it's parent canvas's sorting order and add some offset to the new canvas's sorting order. Here's how you'd do it by hand in inspector:
[image]

I've also created [this simple script/component](https://gist.github.com/somedeveloper00/c48fee9003fbad415874a48859a1c2cf) that does the job dynamically
:
[image]